# Why get error here "Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile-shope\reg.php on line 12"?

Tags: php, html

Here is Php Code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf3t7.png)

And Here html code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qquY7.png)

i get this type of error "Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile-shope\reg.php on line 12" can any one solve it.

Comment: Place your code into the question, and don't make images you link to, if you want help.

Comment: Looks like `$_FILES['file']['name']` isn't actually set. Did you set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `<form>` tag? Double check what your name on the file upload input is as well.

Comment: Basically, you have a bunch of form fields your php script is looking for.  If you submit a form where those fields either don't exist or have no value, then the $_POST will not contain those array elements.  Thus you get the warning.  A warning is not necessarily an error, but good coding would probably have a validation routine that would insure the form data includes all the elements required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that:

- `file_uploads = On` in your php.ini file.
- You have added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your html form.

Also try to debug it by using `print_r($_FILES);`

For more information, checkout this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Thanks,